# How to fix input formatting in Konsole?

Tags: linux, terminal, fish, konsole

Since update to Ubuntu 15.04 and new versions of fish and Konsole text i write to the terminal is being formated differently than before. I don't have a problem with text being bold but some of it's last letters are being cut off depending on length of text. I think that easiest way of explaining that would be screenshot.

[image: a]

there should be visible "pgbouncer config.ini" but it is not. How can I have old behaviour of Konsole/fish?
I have fish version: 2.1.1.dfsg-2 and Konsole version: 4:15.04.1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1.

Comment: Can you try fish 2.2.0 from [the official PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fish-shell/+archive/ubuntu/release-2)? There have been plenty of fixes since 2.1.1, and rendering issues are among them.

Comment: sadly no luck: http://imgur.com/bZv1ziw

Comment: it seems this problem is related to Konsole. running fish on default cinnamon's terminal gives me this result http://imgur.com/4SmGW9h

Comment: What's your locale? What's your $TERM in konsole? Does this work better if you increase the width on the window? Is it related to `pgbouncer` or does it also occur with other commandline contents? (I also use fish in konsole and have never seen this)

Comment: There was something wrong with my Konsole. I've changed my terminal app. It could be either Konsole bug or some bad config entry after upgrading my distro.